# call timeout on apigee deploy flow

Tags: apigee

recently someone told me that the api was down and when I went to check I'm getting

```
<fault><faultstring>The Service is temporarily unavailable</faultstring><detail><errorcode>SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE</errorcode></detail></fault>
```

when I tried to redeploy Im getting the following error message.

http://cl.ly/image/1D2e0L1o2P0p

any clue on what to look for?

Marco

EDIT: the problem went away by itself. I dont like problems that disappear by themselves

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with some of the orgs in our cloud infrastructure, which should now be resolved. Please let us know, if you are still seeing issues.

You can find more details here: https://community.apigee.com/questions/8314/the-revision-is-deployed-and-traffic-can-flow-but.html